# Cholesky decomposition with CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu, cusolver

I am trying to implement Cholesky decomposition using the cuSOLVER library. I am a beginner CUDA programmer and I have always specified block-sizes and grid-sizes, but I am not able to find out how this can be set explicitly by the programmer with cuSOLVER functions.

Here is the documentation: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#introduction

The QR decomposition is implemented using the cuSOLVER library (see the example here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#ormqr-example1) and even there the above two parameters are not set.

To summarize, I have the following questions

- How can the parameters: block-size and grid-size can be set with the cuSOLVER library?
- How is the same being done with the mentioned QR example code in the NVIDIA documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robert Crovella has already answered this question. Here, I'm just providing a full example showing how Cholesky decomposition can be easily performed using the `potrf` function provided by the cuSOLVER library.

The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files are mantained at [this page](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA_Utilities) and omitted here. The example implements the CPU as well as the GPU approach.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_paraMeters.h"

#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>

#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#define prec_save 10

/******************************************/
/* SET HERMITIAN POSITIVE DEFINITE MATRIX */
/******************************************/
// --- Credit to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab
void setPDMatrix(double * __restrict h_A, const int N) {

    // --- Initialize random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    double *h_A_temp = (double *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            h_A_temp[i * N + j] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
            h_A[i * N + j] = 0.5 * (h_A_temp[i * N + j] + h_A_temp[j * N + i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) h_A[i * N + i] = h_A[i * N + i] + N;

}

/************************************/
/* SAVE REAL ARRAY FROM CPU TO FILE */
/************************************/
template <class T>
void saveCPUrealtxt(const T * h_in, const char *filename, const int M) {

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(filename);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) outfile << std::setprecision(prec_save) << h_in[i] << "\n";
    outfile.close();

}

/************************************/
/* SAVE REAL ARRAY FROM GPU TO FILE */
/************************************/
template <class T>
void saveGPUrealtxt(const T * d_in, const char *filename, const int M) {

    T *h_in = (T *)malloc(M * sizeof(T));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_in, d_in, M * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(filename);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) outfile << std::setprecision(prec_save) << h_in[i] << "\n";
    outfile.close();

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(){

    const int N = 1000;

    // --- CUDA solver initialization
    cusolverDnHandle_t solver_handle;
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnCreate(&solver_handle));

    // --- CUBLAS initialization
    cublasHandle_t cublas_handle;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&cublas_handle));

    /***********************/
    /* SETTING THE PROBLEM */
    /***********************/
    // --- Setting the host, N x N matrix
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
    setPDMatrix(h_A, N);

    // --- Allocate device space for the input matrix 
    double *d_A; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, N * N * sizeof(double)));

    // --- Move the relevant matrix from host to device
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, N * N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    /****************************************/
    /* COMPUTING THE CHOLESKY DECOMPOSITION */
    /****************************************/
    // --- cuSOLVE input/output parameters/arrays
    int work_size = 0;
    int *devInfo;           gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&devInfo, sizeof(int)));

    // --- CUDA CHOLESKY initialization
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnDpotrf_bufferSize(solver_handle, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, N, d_A, N, &work_size));

    // --- CUDA POTRF execution
    double *work;   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&work, work_size * sizeof(double)));
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnDpotrf(solver_handle, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, N, d_A, N, work, work_size, devInfo));
    int devInfo_h = 0;  gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&devInfo_h, devInfo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    if (devInfo_h != 0) std::cout << "Unsuccessful potrf execution\n\n" << "devInfo = " << devInfo_h << "\n\n";

    // --- At this point, the lower triangular part of A contains the elements of L. 
    /***************************************/
    /* CHECKING THE CHOLESKY DECOMPOSITION */
    /***************************************/
    saveCPUrealtxt(h_A, "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCholeskyCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCholeskyCUDA\\h_A.txt", N * N);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_A, "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCholeskyCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCholeskyCUDA\\d_A.txt", N * N);

    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnDestroy(solver_handle));

    return 0;

}
```

**EDIT**

Cholesky decomposition requires that the relevant matrix is Hermitian and positive definite. Symmetric and positive definite matrices can be generated by the approach in [How to generate random symmetric positive definite matrices using MATLAB?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab).

The following Matlab code can be used for checking the results

```
clear all
close all
clc

warning off

N = 1000;

% --- Setting the problem solution
x = ones(N, 1);

load h_A.txt
A = reshape(h_A, N, N);

yMatlab = A * x;

Lmatlab = chol(A, 'lower');

xprime      = inv(Lmatlab) * yMatlab;
xMatlab     = inv(Lmatlab') * xprime;

fprintf('Percentage rms of solution in Matlab %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(xMatlab - x).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(x).^2))));

load d_A.txt
LCUDA = tril(reshape(d_A, N, N));

fprintf('Percentage rms of Cholesky decompositions in Matlab and CUDA %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(Lmatlab - LCUDA).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(Lmatlab).^2))));

load xCUDA.txt
fprintf('Percentage rms of solution in Matlab %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(xCUDA - x).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(x).^2))));
```

Comment: I am trying to check the results from matrix size 4 to 4096. Any suggestions on how this matrix can be initialized?

Comment: @yath Cholesky decomposition requires the matrix to be hermitian and positive definite. Symmetric positive definite matrices can be generated by the approach in [How to generate random symmetric positive definite matrices using MATLAB?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab).

Answer (score 3):

You don't set block sizes (or grid sizes) explicitly when using a library like cusolver, or cublas, or cusparse.

The library chooses these, when it actually runs device code internal to the library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. My project-main aim is to evaluate performance for multiple block-size values, how can this be done if the parameters can not be set explicitly?

Comment: There is no way to do that with a library like cusolver, or cublas or cusparse.